# Nexus NPM can't proxy latest selenium-webdriver versions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, npm, nexus

I've got a Nexus NPM repository setup which proxies the default registry at https://registry.npmjs.org.

I am trying to install Protractor, which depends on selenium-webdriver@2.45.1. However, for some odd reason, this version of the selenium-webdriver module doesn't get proxied and returns a 404. This also occurs when I install it manually:

```
npm install selenium-webdriver@2.45.1
```

This is the response:

```
npm http fetch GET http://xxxxx/selenium-webdriver-2.45.1.tgz 
npm http fetch 404 http://xxxxx/selenium-webdriver-2.45.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://xxxxx/selenium-webdriver-2.45.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
```

I'm also getting this response when I try to install previous versions 2.44.x and 2.43.x.

Versions 2.42.1 and older are installed fine.
Other modules are also proxied without issues.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could be causing this? Is it a Nexus configuration issue?

**Edit:** To add, I'm using Sonatype Nexus version 2.11.2-06

Also, I did some digging into the different selenium-webdriver package.json versions. Perhaps that is relevant?

The differences are:

2.42.1 (last working version):

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.8.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "~1.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R list --recursive test"
  },
  "_id": "selenium-webdriver@2.42.1",
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "61984d1583b89c80a9f3bf31623d00bcc82a8d0e",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.42.1.tgz"
  },
  "_from": "selenium-webdriver@2.42.1",
  "_npmVersion": "1.2.18",
  },
  "directories": {},
  "_shasum": "61984d1583b89c80a9f3bf31623d00bcc82a8d0e",
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.42.1.tgz"
}
```

2.45.1 (needed version):

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "0.4.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.2.8",
    "tmp": "0.0.24",
    "ws": "^0.7.1",
    "xml2js": "0.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.11.2",
    "mocha": ">= 1.21.x",
    "multer": "^0.1.7",
    "promises-aplus-tests": "^2.1.0",
    "serve-index": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony -t 600000 --recursive test"
  },
  "_id": "selenium-webdriver@2.45.1",
  "_shasum": "6fc6a8ce385085a7b670edd36a379b2eddadf2c9",
  "_from": "selenium-webdriver@2.45.1",
  "_npmVersion": "2.5.1",
  "_nodeVersion": "0.12.0",
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "6fc6a8ce385085a7b670edd36a379b2eddadf2c9",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.45.1.tgz"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.45.1.tgz"
}
```

Perhaps the difference in NPM version is relevant?

**Edit 2:** Nexus log shows this exception while trying to fetch the module:

```
2015-05-07 09:29:08,048+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 0/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4095460
2015-05-07 09:29:08,454+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 1/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4095460
2015-05-07 09:29:08,939+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 2/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4095840
2015-05-07 09:29:09,314+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 0/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4095460
2015-05-07 09:29:09,939+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 1/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4096000
2015-05-07 09:29:10,392+0200 WARN  [qtp8401575-718] anonymous com.bolyuba.nexus.plugin.npm.service.tarball.internal.TarballSourceImpl - Fetch 2/3 failed for selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 tarball: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4797844; received: 4095460
```

Comment: Does it work without Nexus? This would allow you to isolate if the problem is with Nexus or the metadata for the package upstream and the rest of your tooling.

Comment: Try right clicking on the proxy repo and running "expire cache", this will force a refetch of remote metadata.  If this doesn't fix the issue check the nexus.log to see if there are network errors occurring when it tries to reach the remote at https://registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

Manfred, Yes, I've tried it without Nexus, directly installing it from the NPM registry. This works fine.

@rseddon Tried the "expire cache" option, but this didn't change anything. But thanks for the suggestion on checking the log. A ConnectionClosedException is logged, with the message "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body". 

I've added the full log output to the main post.